# Price drop protection on Apple iPhone

Tags: united-states, credit-card, iphone

Two of my credit cards (Discover and Citi) have programs for cardholders that allow you to buy a product and if the price drops in certain amount of time, file a requests to be reimbursed the difference.

As it is time to upgrade my old phone, I have decided on an iPhone and the latest version is not important to me.  People have told me to wait until the new iPhone comes out later this month because prices on the last model will drop.  Is this an acceptable use of the Citi Price Rewind program, or Discover Price Protection?

A lot of people have iPhones, has anyone successfully filed a price refund voucher for an iPhone, and is it a smooth process?

Comment: They might be restricting their refund offers to cases where the product was available for less _on the date of purchase_ but you did not know about it at the time of purchase.

Comment: And they're almost certainly saying exact same model. Read the paperwork on you particular policy; if in doubt ask the bank or credit card company what documentation is required. I'd say it _should be coveted, but that depends on your specific plan.

Comment: Just wait until next week. The announcement of new phones is scheduled for September 9, and the price drop on the current models ($100, if history is any guide) will be effective within at most 2 weeks. Be warned, however, that when the current model drops to the lower price point, they sometimes reduce the available storage options, so you might not get exactly what you want.